# how to i create a Username shortener?

Tags: vb.net

I have an AD username called "lastname-132" in Textbox1, this string is 12 long, so i want to add the username in to Textbox2, but shortened, in the textbox2 i only have a string length of only 10 available due to other tools this program is using, so i don't want to convert it all the time manually and want to just convert it automatically with a onleave event.

Anyone any idea how to write this?

So the End Result should look like this.

```
'String length can be 20 max.
Textbox1.Text = "lastname-123"
'some code to convert it to this:
'String length 10 max. Numbers and the "-" should stay the same, but remove letters if necessary.
Textbox2.Text = "lastna-123"
```

Comment: What are the rules of the user names?  Do they always end with `-###` or could there be more or fewer numbers?

Comment: Is there always only ONE hyphen?

Comment: Are you using leading zeroes to keep the numeric portion constant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more information, this will assume that there can be multiple hyphens, the number can be of variable length, and you can change the maximum length of the string by changing one variable.

```
Dim username As String = "lastname-123"
Dim max As Integer = 10

Dim lindex As Integer = username.LastIndexOf("-")
Dim numberLength As Integer = username.Length - lindex
Dim number As String = username.Substring(lindex)
Dim justName As String = username.Substring(0, lindex)

If justName.Length + numberLength >= max Then
    username = justName.Substring(0, max - numberLength) & number
End If
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's the concept:

1. Split string based on '-' into 2 strings

   In the example above: 'lastname' and '123'.
2. Check the length of the first string and cut if it is too long

   the program checks 'lastname' and finds that it is too long, then
   cuts it into 'lastna'
3. Combine 'lastna' and '123' back into a string

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you are concentrating only on the restriction of length of characters to be accepted then you can use

> Maxlength

property of the Textbox.

> Ex: Maxlength="10"

restricts the Textbox to accept only 10 characters.

Answer (score -1):

Try to make it fit with for example substring manipulation. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd789093.aspx for more info.